# Invalid rendering of texture

Tags: android, model, opengl-es, libgdx, textures

I have a model, that I load with `AssetManager` and then render it. It is a`g3dj` file, with a png texture. All files are present in the filesystem.

In my case, I load a model from the server and add it to the game. `The texture` is present but is not rendered correctly.

ModelBatch renders my model completely black when I add it after `create()` method in `ApplicationListener`. If I add a model in create() method, it renders correctly.

What is the problem? I already tried recreating `RenderContext`.

**Some code:**

```
@Override
    public void create() {
        //setup camera, environment, create ModelBatch instance
        assetManager = new AssetManager();
        assetManager.load("models/f_base.g3dj", Model.class);
        assetManager.finishLoading();
        Model model = assetManager.get("models/f_base.g3dj");
        modelInstance = new ModelInstance(model);
    }

@Override
public void render() {
    if (assetManager.update()) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        cameraController.update();
        batch.begin(camera);
        batch.render(modelInstance);
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

[image: invalid model]

Comment: Think it'd be better if you censored your textured image tbh. People browse StackOverflow from work and even though it's only cartoon nudity, lots of workplaces have stringent rules about what's appropriate.

Comment: "ModelBatch renders my model completely black when I add it after create() method in ApplicationListener." - When exactly are you creating it? My guess would be you're creating it in a thread that doens't have the OpenGLES context bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found solution. The problem is that AssetManager throws exception with messge: "call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)" if you force loading of AssetManager resources:

```
assetManager.finishLoading();
```

To make AssetManager load resources asynchronyously you need just add resource to queue:

```
assetManager.load(fileHandle.path(), Model.class);
```

and then check if you can render your model with update() method:

```
public void render() {
    if (assetManager.update()) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        cameraController.update();
        batch.begin(camera);
        //model loaded. you can render it.
        batch.end();
    }
}
```